# Ignore blockquotes in wordpress excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

is it possible to make wordpress excerpt ignore the text put in blockquotes? If the opening paragraph is short, and it has blockquote it looks bizarre on the main page.
You can spot an example at http://kmkollman.com/portfolio/, on the post about "logotype design"

My first idea was to setup display:none on these elements, but the excerpt function returns only the text, ignoring html tags.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

edited

```
echo preg_replace('/<blockquote[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/blockquote[^>]*>/', '',  get_the_excerpt())
```

Comment: It simply doesn't work, the part of the text that is placed within a blockquote still appears in the excerpt result.

Comment: can you show how your theme displaying excerpt ? ps: some theme has their own excerpt function , you can replace it with my code [tested]

Comment: This is the loop I am using on the page, with your code added:
https://pastebin.com/0qEHHstc
It still will display me the text from inside the blockquote, but now I think it may be due to the fact that what wordpress does is wrapping the <p> within <blockquote>?

Comment: I am sorry for  misunderstood. So you want to remove text inside blockquote. try this regex = 
echo preg_replace('/<blockquote[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/blockquote[^>]*>/', '',  get_the_excerpt())

Comment: ps : you may also need add manualy <p> tag if it's worked for your excerpt

Comment: Thank you for help! But as far as I see that regex should work, it doesn't in this case - I think it may be fault of how get_the_excerpt processes the content (if it's stripped off the tag before preg_replace() works on it, it will not select properly).

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work on your case. I tested in my localsite, write exceprt manually in excerpt form and it's worked.